# Web3 server-side trouble connect with ganache

Tags: web3js, javascript, nodejs, ganache

I need to create server in nodejs that will create transaction to blockchain and i have trouble to connect my nodejs app with ganache. Look at my code:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'); // ganache address
console.log(web3.eth.accounts); // should print 10 accounts but its error like eth is undefined
```

In my dependencies

```
"web3": "^0.20.2"
```

Using this code on client-side works, what am i missing?

Comment: Is ganache running on the server?

Comment: server is my laptop so yes

Comment: Probably won't help, but try `http://127.0.0.1:7545`

Comment: nothing changed, im wonder if my web3 version is ok?

Comment: me to having the same problem please help[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86ACs.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86ACs.png)

Comment: if you didn't find a solution for your issue on stackexchange, it would be better to ask separate question with more details.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30331)

Comment: A potential solution I worked through on my own [SO](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60335/web3-empty-object-server-side-in-meteor) which may or may note be related to this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
var web3 = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545');
```

You're instantiating a provider instead of instantiating `Web3`. It should be this:

```
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:7545'));
```